# C++ template member function having pointer reference template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```
class BI {
public:
   virtual void fun() = 0;
   virtual ~BI() {}
};

class B : public BI {
public:
   void fun() {}
};

template <typename T>
class A {
   T* obj;
public:
   void funT(const T*&) /* adding reference is creating error */;
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::funT(const T*& obj) {
}

int main() {
   A<B> obj;
   obj.funT(new B());
}
```

when compiling the above code with g++ compiler, I am getting the error: *no matching function for call to A::funT(B*)*. But when I remove the reference '**&**' operator from the funT() declaration as `void funT(const T* obj)`, then it compiles and works fine. Why the reference operator is not allowed here?

Comment: Why do you want reference? Does `funT` modify the pointer itself and you need to return that? Or do you really want a const object there? Could you include some code that describes the use of `obj` in `funT`? I'm suspecting you wanted to pass the param as const ref and misplaced the `&`, and you wanted to write `T*& const obj`

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for a **reference to a pointer**, you can't get references (unless they're C++11 rvalue references) to **temporary values**.

Make sure you have a **lvalue** passed as parameter to have the reference working.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class BI {
public:
   virtual void fun() = 0;
   virtual ~BI() {}
};

class B : public BI {
public:
   void fun() {}
};

template <typename T>
class A {
   T* obj;
public:
   void funT(const T*&);
};

template <typename T>
void A<T>::funT(const T*& obj) {
}

int main() {
   A<B> obj;
   const B* ptr = new B(); // <--  This is an lvalue
   obj.funT(ptr);
   delete ptr; // Also clean it up after you used it
}
```

http://ideone.com/T4QJzi

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simple program which exhibits the same problem:

```
void fun(const int*&) {}

int main() {
    int x;
    fun(&x);
}
```

It yields the following error:

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘const int*&’
from an rvalue of type ‘int*’
```

That makes sense. `fun` takes an argument of type "reference to **non-const** pointer to const `int`", and we tried to pass it a temporary of type "pointer to `int`". References to non-const types don't bind to temporaries, because temporaries are usually immutable. In this case, if we were allowed to pass `&x` as the argument to `fun`, then `fun` would be able to modify the address of `x`, which doesn't make any sense.

As you noticed, removing the `&` makes the code well formed:

```
void fun(const int*) {}
```

Now we are simply passing a pointer to `int` where a value of type pointer to const `int` is expected, which is a simple implicit conversion.

Alternatively, you might have intended for `fun` to take an argument of type "reference to **const** pointer to `int`":

```
void fun(int* const&) {}
```

Or a reference to const pointer to const `int`:

```
void fun(const int* const&) {}
```

But a reference to a const pointer is kind of silly, as a simple pointer would be just as good.

Finally, you could keep your original declaration of `fun`, and just avoid trying to pass a temporary as its argument.

Answer (score 0):

The error msg is clear. Parameter type is of ***reference to pointer to T***, but you are sending ***pointer to T***. Temporaries cannot be passed as *reference* in this case. You can write:

```
int main() {
 A<B> obj;
 const B* b=new B(); //create a lvalue
 obj.funT(b);
 delete b; // make sure to release memory.
}
```